# How to stop nvidia-settings from installing gnome desktop?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, gnome, nvidia-settings

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 Server edition with minimal X11 installed (no desktop managers)

I want to install nvidia-settings ver 470 but it looks like it wants to pull in gnome desktop. Any ideas on how to stop this? Am I reading this right that it will pull in gnome desktop? I used `sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests` but it still brought in a ton of gnome software.

Just to note....on my Gentoo system nvidia-settings version 370 didn't pull in gnome desktop. Not sure why it is on Ubuntu with version 470

Comment: You mean 20.04 server edition?

Comment: Just tested, and it does not pull in `gnome-desktop`. Where did you get it from? The package by that name isn't even in the repositores.

Comment: @mikewhatever I got it from here https://dpaste.org/7xRS#L11,15,53,57,63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of dependencies. See terminal output from 20.04 LTS installed from [mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso):

```
$ apt-cache depends nvidia-settings
nvidia-settings
  Depends: pkg-config
    pkgconf
  Depends: screen-resolution-extra
  Depends: libvdpau1
 |Depends: libgtk-3-0
  Depends: libgtk2.0-0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcairo2
  Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libjansson4
  Depends: libpango-1.0-0
  Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: libxnvctrl0
  Depends: libxxf86vm1
  Conflicts: 
  Replaces: 
    nvidia-settings
```

```
apt-cache depends screen-resolution-extra
screen-resolution-extra
  Depends: 
    python3
  Depends: python3-xkit
 |Depends: gnome-shell
 |Depends: policykit-1-gnome
  Depends: 
    gnome-flashback
    gnome-shell
    lxpolkit
    lxqt-policykit
    mate-polkit
    policykit-1-gnome
    polkit-kde-agent-1
    ukui-polkit
  Depends: python3-gi
```

In the above output you should note that gnome-shell is not located in Recommends or Suggests sections, so is not optional.

Or use packages.ubuntu.com - check pages for [`nvidia-settings`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/nvidia-settings) and its dependency named [`screen-resolution-extra`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/screen-resolution-extra).

With known Gentoo terminology this means that Ubuntu uses gnome or gnome-shell USE-flag for nvidia-settings package.

---

Possible way to get minimal set of dependent package is to install `lxpolkit` package instead of `gnome-shell` as follows:

> ```
> $ sudo apt install lxpolkit nvidia-settings --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> The following additional packages will be installed:
>   adwaita-icon-theme dbus-user-session dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core glib-networking
>   glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gsettings-desktop-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme humanity-icon-theme
>   libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libbrotli1 libcairo-gobject2
>   libcairo2 libcolord2 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdconf1 libdpkg-perl libepoxy0 libfontconfig1 libgdbm-compat4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
>   libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgraphite2-3 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-common libharfbuzz0b libjansson4 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8
>   libjpeg8 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common liblcms2-2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libperl5.30 libpixman-1-0
>   libpolkit-agent-1-0 libproxy1v5 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5
>   libunique-1.0-0 libvdpau1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwebp6 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1
>   libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxnvctrl0 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxxf86vm1 lxsession-data perl perl-modules-5.30
>   pkg-config policykit-1 python3-xkit screen-resolution-extra ubuntu-mono
> Suggested packages:
>   colord cups-common debian-keyring gnupg | gnupg2 gcc | c-compiler binutils patch git bzr gvfs liblcms2-utils librsvg2-bin perl-doc
>   libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl make libb-debug-perl liblocale-codes-perl dpkg-dev
> Recommended packages:
>   at-spi2-core libfile-fcntllock-perl libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgtk-3-bin libgail-common libgtk2.0-bin vdpau-driver-all | vdpau-driver
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   adwaita-icon-theme dbus-user-session dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core glib-networking
>   glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gsettings-desktop-schemas gtk-update-icon-cache hicolor-icon-theme humanity-icon-theme
>   libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libbrotli1 libcairo-gobject2
>   libcairo2 libcolord2 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdconf1 libdpkg-perl libepoxy0 libfontconfig1 libgdbm-compat4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
>   libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgraphite2-3 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-common libharfbuzz0b libjansson4 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8
>   libjpeg8 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common liblcms2-2 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libperl5.30 libpixman-1-0
>   libpolkit-agent-1-0 libproxy1v5 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5
>   libunique-1.0-0 libvdpau1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1 libwebp6 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1
>   libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbcommon0 libxnvctrl0 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxxf86vm1 lxpolkit lxsession-data nvidia-settings
>   perl perl-modules-5.30 pkg-config policykit-1 python3-xkit screen-resolution-extra ubuntu-mono
> 0 upgraded, 92 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> Need to get 26.2 MB/26.2 MB of archives.
> After this operation, 133 MB of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
> ...
> ```

and optionally install minimal desktop environment by

```
sudo apt-get install xinit openbox slim
```

or install full Lubuntu desktop by

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop^
```

Comment: I don't mind if it's gnome-shell....but does that mean it will bring the whole desktop in? From https://dpaste.org/7xRS#L15,53,57,63 I see `gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0` being pulled in.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  How come `gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0` shows up in my output but not yours? https://dpaste.org/7xRS#L11,15,53,57,63

Comment: It is unclear. I do not see the installation command, and do not know list of installed packages.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests`

Comment: I have also installed `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470-server` and  `nvidia-utils-470-server` if it matters

Comment: You have to use exact my command `sudo apt install lxpolkit nvidia-settings --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests` which avoids gnome shell installation. Please read my answer carefully.